# Limit image resolution on upload file for specific field

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, uploads

I use Woocommerce ,when add product I have a form with two "upload file" fields. (product image field) and (product gallery images field).

when the user uploads an image for the first field (product image field) I want to limit image size to (640*640 max).

And when he uploads an image for the second field (product gallery images field) I want to limit image size to (300*300 max).

Is it possible to set different sizes for two specific fields?

Please note that I use media editor upload for wordpress

Comment: Do you want to disallow uploading files in dimensions different than 640x640 and 300x300 or resize the images after the upload? If you want to resize them only then you can do that as explained in WC documentation here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/

Comment: I want to disallow uploading files in dimensions different than 640*640 for first field and 300*300 for second field